# Microsoft Teams - Not able to send a card

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to send a cards to my teams webhook as mentioned in this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference

Following is my code. However it's not working. I don't see any error either.

I get `400` status code.

**code**

```
import json
import urllib3


class TeamsWebhookException(Exception):
    """custom exception for failed webhook call"""
    pass


class ConnectorCard:
    def __init__(self, hookurl, http_timeout=60):
        self.http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        self.payload = {}
        self.hookurl = hookurl
        self.http_timeout = http_timeout

    def text(self, mtext):
        self.payload["text"] = mtext
        return self

    def send(self):
        headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
        r = self.http.request(
                'POST',
                f'{self.hookurl}',
                body=json.dumps(self.payload).encode('utf-8'),
                headers=headers, timeout=self.http_timeout)
        if r.status == 200:
            return True
        else:
            print(r.status)
            print(r.error)
            raise TeamsWebhookException(r.reason)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myTeamsMessage = ConnectorCard("https://xxx.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/02f9df4b-8e93-4b8c-9449-0916965d46b1@6f8518e1-bbdc-41ae-a82c-024046d586dd/IncomingWebhook/270de670afcc4364bf432be076465054/9fb627e3-c22e-4741-8aaa-b962490e5fee")
    myTeamsMessage.text("this is my test message to the teams channel.")
    payload = """{
  "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.o365connector",
  "content": {
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": "John Doe commented on Trello",
    "title": "Project Tango",
    "sections": [
        {
            "activityTitle": "John Doe commented",
            "activitySubtitle": "On Project Tango",
            "activityText": "Here are the designs",
            "activityImage": "http://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/MSC12_Oscar_002.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "Details",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "name": "Labels",
                    "value": "Designs, redlines"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Due date",
                    "value": "Dec 7, 2016"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Attachments",
                    "value": "[final.jpg](http://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/WIN14_Jan_04.jpg)"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Images",
            "images": [
                {
                    "image":"http://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/MicrosoftSurface_024_Cafe_OH-06315_VS_R1c.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "image":"http://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/WIN12_Scene_01.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "image":"http://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/WIN12_Anthony_02.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "potentialAction": [
        {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "ViewAction",
            "name": "View in Trello",
            "target": [
                "https://trello.com/c/1101/"
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}"""
    myTeamsMessage.payload = payload
    myTeamsMessage.send()
```

Comment: We tried sending the above payload through Postman and it worked successfully. Attaching a screenshot of the same. It seems like there is an issue with the client side code. Could you please check if the code to send this payload using incoming webhook is correct?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7YcE.png

Comment: Could you please check if the code to send this payload using incoming webhook is correct?